# Android RecyclerView pass and display Item data depending on condition

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement

I have a RecyclerViewActivity and data for RecyclerView:

```
     // get a reference to recyclerView
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

     // this is data for recyclerview

        CardData cardData[] = {
            new CardData("Bread", R.drawable.bread),
            new CardData("Dairy", R.drawable.dairy),
            new CardData("Meat", R.drawable.meat) ...}
```

Each CardData connected to different Activity with simple ListView.

Now I used Shared Preferences and boolean variable to check if there are some items in every ListView. After check completes - pass true/ false value to the RecyclerViewActivity:

```
      SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("filename", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean a = pref.getBoolean("key1", false);
    Boolean b = pref.getBoolean("key2", false);
    Boolean c = pref.getBoolean("key3", false);
```

Now what I need to do - is **to display CardData depending on a/b/c values**. If I receive **a: true** - **need to display some additional image indicator in my data set.** Something like this:

```
       CardData cardData[] = {
            if (!a) {
            new CardData("Bread", R.drawable.bread, R.drawable.indicator)
            }
            else {
            new CardData("Bread", R.drawable.bread) };

            if (!b) {
            new CardData("Dairy", R.drawable.dairy, R.drawable.indicator)
            }
            else {
            new CardData("Dairy", R.drawable.dairy};

            ...
            }
```

The problem is that I don't now where and how exactly can I set this condition. Inside CardData like above it does'n work - gives me a syntax error..

Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: This is what I understand -- you're trying to add `CardData` objects to the array, while selection of the constructor depends upon the value of booleans a,b,c. Correct?

Comment: Yes. And I want to add them depending on values of a,b,c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't breaking it into smaller, more manageable steps.

You can do it in this way:

```
// initialise the array with size 3
CardData cardData[] = new CardData[3];

// start adding elements now
// insert first object by checking flag "a"
if (a) {
    cardData[0] = new CardData("Bread", R.drawable.bread);
}
else {
    cardData[0] = new CardData("Bread", R.drawable.bread, R.drawable.indicator);
}

// insert second object by checking flag "b"
if (b) {
    cardData[1] = new CardData("Dairy", R.drawable.dairy);
}
else {
    cardData[1] = new CardData("Dairy", R.drawable.dairy, R.drawable.indicator);
}

// and so on...
```

Comment: I have changed my code as per your suggestion and it's work now! Thank you a lot!!!